# How to keep a Google Doc spreadsheet updated 'real time' (constantly) from an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I have a fairly complex (for me anyway) excel spreadsheet which keeps track of team time(s) for a multi-stage sled-dog race http://copperdog150.com/.

the excel spread-sheet calculates time per leg for each team, over all time, mph, order of finish, overall winner, etc, etc.  the excel spreadsheet is in a laptop which travels with the race.

i hope to keep using the excel spreadsheet (is it worth trying to 'convert' it into a google spreadsheet?  I am afraid I will be limited; I have macros for one) but was hoping I could have google docs constantly 'import' my data (e.g., times, overall winner) so HQ, race directors, and the like can just look on the web (phone/computer/tablet) to see the results... or maybe its having excel constantly 'export' the data.

i will be in the woods but my laptop has wireless and my phone (assuming I have signal) works great as a hotspot.  data in the excel spreadsheet changes constantly so I would like the google spreadsheet to be 'real time'.

is this possible? if so, how? I am not an expert...

thanks in advance, kiko

Comment: You should add the Google-Spreadsheets-API tag

Answer (score 0):

There's `importxml` function in Google sheet to import xml data and you can also parse the data. It's fairly complicated. (more doc on `importxml` https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Another alternative is to use Script Editor (Select Tools -> Script editor). Essentially, you write your own script (Google App script, similar to JavaScript) to fetch and parse the data (`JSON`, etc).

Sometime, it's necessary to create a custom script if the dataset is complicated. But, some other time, `importxml` will just do.

This is a good start (`importxml` or Script Editor): http://www.computerworld.com/article/2469616/business-intelligence/business-intelligence-79661-how-to-create-an-automatically-updating-spreadsheet.html

And Google Developer doc:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external?hl=en

Answer (score -3):

Check out the Google API: [Google Spreadsheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/)

Comment: i have been there... and various other sites as well.  it hurts my brain... seems a little advanced for me.  but i'll keep trying to get it...

Comment: You should definitely add the Google-Spreadsheets-API tag as someone else may be able to get you started. That API is what you use to update Google spreadsheets.

Comment: Or how about publishing to a website every minute or so from Excel so avoiding the Google API.

Comment: i will see about adding an API tag... and i did try publishing as a webpage... it works, but how am i automatically "upload" the file to a webpage?  or have the webpage call out the file?

Comment: As to publishing > uploading > website; I don't have experience with that; hopefully not too difficult. Suggest you start a new question for that. You should be able to do that from Excel VBA.

Comment: sounds good!  thanks for all your help... i'll keep this open for now and see if i get something over the weekend.